# Ordered List in Arabic not working

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I need show data in Order List in order. example 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4.....

When I use following CSS, it shows table of content in proper order for English and if I have to show similar thing in Arabic then it doesn't work in Arabic. It shows Arabic number when I use it with `ul` but then I lose the formatting like `3.1, 3.2....`

```
ol li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item; font-weight:bold; }
```

How can I format order list to show Table of Content in ordered list as

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 3.1
5. 3.2
6. 3.3
7. 4
8. 5

https://jsfiddle.net/rkmv3rn3/

Comment: You mean you want to show the `ul` like `ol`?

Comment: Arabic number doesnt work with OL when i add `.` I need it to work with ol

Comment: You mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/rkmv3rn3/1/)?

Comment: @Harry, I missed the trick.. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbering for the `ol` is actually done using counters and not default list styles. So, the counter's numbering style should be set to `arabic-indic` (the unprefixed version) instead of `list-style-type`.

The key part of the snippet code is the below line where we set the styling. The third parameter in the counter function is the the style of the numbering (first is the counter name and second is separator).

```
content: counters(item, ".", arabic-indic)" ";
```

```css
ul {
  direction: rtl;
  list-style-type: arabic-indic;
}
.handbook-page ol {
  color: #687074;
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: arabic-indic;
  direction: rtl;
  counter-reset: item;
  color: #687074;
}
ol li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #687074;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".", arabic-indic)" ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>LIST OL </h1>
<div class="page-content">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<h1>LIST UL </h1>
<div class="page-ul">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

For displaying the output as 1.3, 2.3, 3.3 in Arabic instead of 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 (for sub-items of third `li`), it seems like self nesting counters cannot be used because the number always gets appended and not added at the front. If this is needed, we have to use a different counter for each level of the lis and then manually add the sub-counter's value at the front like in below snippet.

```css
ul {
  direction: rtl;
  list-style-type: arabic-indic;
}
.page-content > ol {
  direction: rtl;
  counter-reset: item-level1, item-level2;
  color: #687074;
}
.page-content > ol > ol{
  direction: rtl;
  counter-reset: item-level2;
  color: #687074;
}
ol li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.page-content > ol li{
  counter-increment: item-level1;
}
.page-content > ol > ol li{
  counter-increment: item-level2;
}
ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #687074;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(item-level1, arabic-indic)" ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
ol ol li:before {
  content: counter(item-level2, arabic-indic) "." counter(item-level1, arabic-indic)" ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>LIST OL </h1>
<div class="page-content">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<h1>LIST UL </h1>
<div class="page-ul">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In Arabic it is showing number as  `3.1`, `3.2` while it should be `1.3`, `2.3`, 3.3`,`4.3`.... Sorry i cant copy arabic numbers so i am using number for reference

Comment: I meant like this `١٠٣٫٢٠٣٫٣٠٣٫٤٠٣٫٥٠٣`

Comment: @Learning: But the original fiddle itself shows it the same way only (in English).

Comment: I am not sure if i am able to explain for English version  we show sub page as 3.1, 3.2.... but for arabic version it should be `1.3, 2.3` | while is is showing as  `١٠٣٫٢٠٣` it should show like this  ....<--`٣٠١٫٣٠١`

Comment: My apology for that.. I will mark you answer as correct any ways, Just wanted to know if that is possible..